# Dynamic onkeydown not working on children with contentEditable parent

Tags: javascript, html

Anyone got an idea why this doesnt work? Im tyring to add the listener to the children rather than to the body so I can later disable certain keystrokes (like the return key).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(i in divs){
        divs[i].onkeydown=function(event){alert('ok:'+event)}
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload='test()' contentEditable ="true">
<div>test 1</div>
<div>test 2</div>
<div>test 3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

Preferably, Is there any way to prevent bubbling to the child div if I put the listener on the parent tag? I basically need to occasionally disallow return breaks in this setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made the body editable but not the children, therefore you'll never be able to capture keystrokes for the children. Make the children editable instead of the body.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/sDdN3/

*Updated fiddle to include up/down arrow support (see comment)

Comment: Got it - Thanks. One problem now is that you cant use the up & down arrows to change lines! Is there any way to prevent bubbling to the child element if the listener is on the parent? I basically need to occasionally disallow return breaks in this setup.

Comment: I'm not sure about browser compatibility with next/previousElementSibling, but I've updated that link with new code. http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/sDdN3/ Note I didn't include logic to check if next/prev exists first. But you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks Kai - I appreciate the effort but I really need to be able to select text and copy and paste etc as you would if the body was contentEditable. Is there really no way to kill an event bubble to the child using a listener on the parent?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your divs in another div, make it content editable and put the listener on it:

```
<script>
function test(){
    var div = document.getElementById('container');
    div.onkeydown = function(event) {
            event = event || window.event;
            alert('ok: ' + event)
        };
    }
}
</script>


<body onload='test()'>
  <div id="container" contentEditable ="true">
    <div>test 1</div>
    <div>test 2</div>
    <div>test 3</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but this causes the same problem as having the listener on the body